# Solution of the differential equation $2\,y\, dx +(3x^2+y^2)\, dy =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please give me some hint to solve first order first degree differential equation:$2\,y\,dx +(3x^2+y^2)\, dy =0$. This cannot be solved by variable separable method. This is not exact or linear equation either. Putting $y=vx $ will not help. So I am clueless now. A small hint will be sufficient.

Comment: The solution containes the Bessel-function.

Comment: Can't we solve this by usual methods?

Comment: I think you will need a numerical method!

Answer (score 3):

$$2\,y\,dx +(3x^2+y^2)\, dy =0$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{3}{2y}x^2-\frac12 $$ 
This is a Riccati ODE.

The method to transform the  non-linear first order ODE into a linear second order ODE is shown in : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html , Eqs.$(4-6)$.

Let : $\quad x=\frac{2y}{3} \frac{u'(y)}{u(y)}$

$dx=\frac23 \frac{u'(y)}{u(y)}dy+\frac23 y\frac{u''}{u}dy-\frac23 y\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}dy$
$$2y\left(\frac23 \frac{u'(y)}{u(y)}dy+\frac23 y\frac{u''}{u}dy-\frac23 y\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}dy \right) +\left(3\left(\frac23 y\frac{u'}{u} \right)^2+y^2\right) dy =0$$
After simplification :
$$u''  +\frac{1}{y}u'+ \frac34 u =0$$
This is a Bessel ODE. The solutions are :
$$u(y)=c_1J_0\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)+c_2Y_0\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)$$
$J_0$ and $Y_0$ are the Bessel functions of first and second kind respectively.
$$u'(y)=c_1\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)+c_2\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}Y_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)$$
$$x(y)=\sqrt{\frac23}\:y\:\frac{c_1J_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)+c_2Y_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)}{c_1J_0\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)+c_2Y_0\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)}$$
Note : The function $x(y)$ can be written with only one arbitrary constant $\frac{c_0}{c_1}$ or $\frac{c_1}{c_0}$.

There is probably no closed form for the inverse function $y(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:**

A possible approach would be
$$
{{dy} \over {dx}} =  - {{2y} \over {3x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} }} =- {1 \over {\left( {y - i\sqrt 3 \,x} \right)}} - {1 \over {\left( {y + i\sqrt 3 \,x} \right)}}
$$
The component equations 
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{dy} \over {dx}} =  - {1 \over {\left( {y + ia\,x} \right)}}\quad \left| {\;a =  \pm \sqrt 3 } \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Leftrightarrow \quad {{d\left( {y + ia\,x} \right)} \over {dx}} =  - {1 \over {\left( {y + ia\,x} \right)}} - ia\quad  \Leftrightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left( {y + ia\,x} \right)' = f\left( {y + ia\,x} \right) \cr} 
$$
are "1st order autonomous DE", that falls in the class
of the ["Chini's equations"](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor/Chini).

WolframAlpha gives a solution in terms of the Lambert function.

Comment: @Dale: I do not catch the meaning of your comment.

Comment: What does WA mean?